Passing value to provider with generic type
I have a typing problem -
inside my app I have value that I need to pass to the provider,
the only place that knows the type is the app function,
the problem is - I need the child to know the value type.
import React, {createContext, useContext, ReactNode} from 'react';

export interface AppDependencies<T, U> {
    somethingWithType: T; 
    somethingWithOtherType: U; 

}

const Context = createContext<AppDependencies<any, any>>(undefined);

interface AppDependenciesProviderProps<T, U> {
    value: AppDependencies<T, U>;
    children: ReactNode;
}


export const AppDependenciesProvider = <T, U>({
    value,
    children,
}: AppDependenciesProviderProps<T, U>) => {
    return <Context.Provider value={value}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

export const useAppDependencies = <T, U>() => {
    const context = useContext(Context);

    return context as AppDependencies<T, U>; /
};



and inside of my app function:
const appDependencies: AppDependencies<typeof somethingWithType, typeof somethingWithOtherType> = {
  somethingWithOtherType,
  somethingWithType
};

render(
  <AppDependenciesProvider value={appDependencies}>
            <Main />
 </AppDependenciesProvider>,
  rootEl
);

but still the child don't know the type of the values
I get this error:
Property 'something' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
any suggestions?

You declare const Context = createContext<AppDependencies<any, any>>(undefined); so your application thinks that the context contains an object of type
{
    somethingWithType : any ; 
    somethingWithOtherType : any ; 
}

